# Reduce Postback Flicker ASP.NET Webpage/Chrome Browser

Tags: html, asp.net, meta-tags

I know for IE the following meta tags can be used to reduce the postback flicker

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
```

Is there any way to accomplish this or something similar to this in chrome without an AJAX update panel.

The update panel and partial postbacks won't really work for this website so if there is not another option I will just accept the postback flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to reconsider your design for your website.  AJAX was built to eliminate postback freezes and keep the UI responsive and fluent.

One suggestion I would have for this, is when you first get onto the page use something similar to spin.js while the necessary data loads via an AJAX call, and once the data is available, stop the spinner and display the data to the user.

spin.js - http://spin.js.org/